# Chomedriver "The driver is not executable"

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have my chromedriver and chromedriver.exe right in project folder.
I'm creating instance of driver with this code.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
LoggingPreferences log_prefs = new LoggingPreferences();
log_prefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.SEVERE);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, log_prefs);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

And it's ok on local windows (if we change "chromedriver" to "chromedriver.exe") , but when i'm running it on CentOS i got error message: "The driver is not executable".

Answer (score 25):

Make it executable:
In CentOs use `chmod +x chromedriver`

Comment: now there is another error : "error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: seems that it's related to the issue that chromdriver for windows will not work on linux: you can try this solution: http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=440#c7

Comment: I'm using chromedriver for linux and chromium since i can't correctly install chrome on CentOS , cause of GLIBCXX_3.4.15.

Answer (score 1):

1. If User is using Unix that time first checks folder or chromedriver permission.
2. Permission is missing then use below command.
3. `chmod 777 *`
4. Above command change folder permission and Issue will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems but in my case the everything was working fine but suddenly I started getting this error, so It wouldn't be access problem I thought.

So for reference to set the chrome driver or firefox driver I was using below snippet.

```
Utils.setSystemProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                classLoader.getSystemResource("utilityJars" + File.separator + "chromedriver_mac").getPath());
```

I think case the path is in target folder when classes are compiled.
So the value of

```
classLoader.getSystemResource("utilityJars" + File.separator + "chromedriver_mac").getPath()
```

is

> /{user.dir}/target/classes/utilityJars/chromedriver_mac

So may be it had some issue accessing chromedriver on that path, may be not compiled or something not sure, but I just deleted the target folder and re-executed it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. The first two answers given worked for me but you can also resolve the permission issue by going to the file (gecko file) that you have in your folder, right click>>Properties and then change the permissions from there.

Answer (score 0):

my driver files were in my eclipse project - resources folder. Funny thing - if you go to the driver and check the properties of chromedriver exe file. It did not have the execute permissions. set that and apply and close. I was good to go.